# Language support problems

Tags: language-support

I'm running 11.04. I want the system language to be in German. When I go to *Language Support* and *Install/Remove Languages*, I check the German box and *Apply Changes*.

However I'm told that the package is already installed and that there isn't any need for an installation. Expanding the *Details* shows:

```
Package [dbus.String(u'libreoffice-gnome')] is already installed
```

However, German doesn't appear in the *Language for menus and windows* list. How should I resolve this?

The problem is the same when I tried Esperanto and Afrikaans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I resolved this. I'll answer the question just in case anyone else has a similar problem.

I went through and did `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gnome`. Upon which I tried again and got the same error except it was with `libreoffice-draw`, and then `librdf0`. After that it let me install German.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem.

While using Ubuntu 11.10 and trying to install French language, I got the error:

```
Package [dbus.String(u'thunderbird')] is already installed
```

As it would be too time consuming to uninstall, reinstall and reconfigure thunderbird (as adviced in some other answer), I looked around for a different fix.

What I found out was that I had some pending updates in the "Update Manager" utility.

All I had to do was to launch "Update Manager" and click on "Install Updates".

After that, it succeeded installing the French language pack.

So, my tip is: **check for pending updates before trying to install a new language pack**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log out and choose the language for your session. At the login prompt, select your user, then look at the bottom of the screen. You'll find a language selector there.

Comment: It only gives me the option of Chinese and about 5 or six variants of English.